# Getting the delphi color values for excel chart lines

Tags: delphi, excel, colors, line, charts

When Excel draws lines on a chart, it assigns default colors to the traces for each data series.  Black for the first, cyan for the second, etc.  Is the assignment of these colors documented?  I want to draw traces on a graph using Delphi but want to keep the colors the same as Excel would use (the Delphi app is replacing stuff currently done with Excel workbooks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Chart fill' and 'chart line' default colors are accessible from the menu: Tools -> Options -> Colors (at least when excel had a menu - I don't know about newer versions). Default colors can be changed per workbook and hence they're a property of the workbook. There are 56 colors in total on the 'Color' option page, with 8 of them belonging to chart fills and 8 to chart lines.

If you're doing automation you can retrieve a workbook default color by:

```
TColor(XL.Workbooks[1].Colors[Index])
```

where 'XL' is the excel application, '1' is the workbook index and 'Index' is a number between 1 and 56. A little test with an earlier excel version shows index 17-24 are fill colors and 25-32 are line colors. But you do your own tests in case there has been changes.

BTW, I am surprised about your problem that Delphi overriding default colors..

Comment: Misunderstanding.  When I said "the Delphi app is replacing stuff currently done with Excel workbooks" what I meant was: the customer currently uses Excel to produce his charts.  I am writing a Delphi app to replace what Excel is currently doing for him, and I want my chart line colors to be allocated in the same way that Excel does, so that their charts will still have the same assignment of line colors.  What I need to know is Pen.Color := ExcelChartLineColor (0), but your suggestion should work if I throw together a quick and dirty app to print out the colors

Comment: Sigh!.. I'd appreciate for a comment reasoning the down-vote.

Comment: @user - I figure it would be a little bit unusual if you down-voted and accepted the answer at the same time. :) Well, what I'd really like to know is rather the reason of the down-vote... Anyway, thanks all the same. :)

Comment: Hi - I didn't down-vote you! At least I don't believe I did.  I thought I had up-voted your answer, and then marked your answer as correct, How can I see whether I downvoted you/undo the downvote if indeed I accidentally did?

Comment: @user - Your rep would be decreased by 1 due to a down-vote, I think you would have noticed that. And, one of the arrows beside the answer should look different, that should be the vote you've cast. Finally, as far as I am aware the down-vote came long after you've accepted the answer, so I don't think it's from you. :) BTW, I *never* thought you've downvoted the answer, if any of my comments hinted otherwise it's only because of my English and I'm sorry for that.